# Specific Contents are not visible by using or by without using scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, scrollview

Following is my xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/contact_us"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Contact us"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/vai" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Worldwide"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                    android:text="Version 1.0"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#bdb9b8">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Group of Companies"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#bdb9b8">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Global Representativess"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/last"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="AgroProducts" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AgroProducts" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem with my layout is that,

1. The linearlayout of id `last` is not fully visible.
2. I tried to encapsulate the entire layout within scrollview but if i do so , the second view pager is not getting visible. Is there any alternative to overcome this scenario?

Comment: Move your `last Linear Layout` above `View Pager`.

Comment: now the second view pager is getting invisible

Comment: fix layout_height of second Viewpager.

Comment: @KaruppuMGR Check my answer below.

Comment: if you plan to just launch you app in some device that is ok but you should consider different screen sizes and in this case if someone want to use it in the smaller screensize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to give `Orientation` to your `Linear Layout`. and Define it above your second `View Pager` your `last Linear Layout`. I have applied some changes to your `Layout`.

**Refer this.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#EBEBEB">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Contact us"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Worldwide"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                android:text="Version 1.0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#bdb9b8">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Group of Companies"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#bdb9b8">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Global Representativess"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/last"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="AgroProducts"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="AgroProducts"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="AgroProducts"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="AgroProducts"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="AgroProducts"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="AgroProducts"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: default orientaion is **android:orientation="horizontal"** so no need

Comment: @AmitVaghela See his `last Linear Layout` is not visible at all so i have defined vertical orientation and move above view pager. i have checked and now with above code it is showing as he expect. Let him apply this first bro. See my changes with his OP `last Linear Layout`.

Comment: Yeah bro but the linear layout with id last has to be below the second view pager bro

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough space to show this layout.
if you don't use you may have to add 
android:weight sum to the container layout(the biggest one)

- android:weightSum="3" (for example)

Then give each child layout the value you want, but make sure the summation of all values equels the weightsum

- android:layout_weight="1" (for example)

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5" 
        >
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">
    < TextView />
    < TextView />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#bdb9b8"
            android:layout_weight="2">
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
  </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

Or you can use ScrollView:

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#EBEBEB">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Contact us"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Worldwide"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                android:text="Version 1.0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#bdb9b8">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Group of Companies"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#bdb9b8">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Global Representativess"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/last"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AgroProducts" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I did some changes to your code.

Comment: it hides the viewpager bro

Answer (score 0):

Check this below code :

**Add ScrollView to your parent Linear layout and give layout_weight to child elements**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="11" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#EBEBEB" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/contact_us" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Contact us"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/vai" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Worldwide"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                        android:text="Version 1.0"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </LinearLayout >
            </LinearLayout >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#bdb9b8" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Group of Companies"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#bdb9b8" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Global Representativess"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/pager2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/last"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="6" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Agro-Products" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Agro-Products" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Agro-Products" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Agro-Products" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Agro-Products" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Agro-Products" />
            </LinearLayout >
        </LinearLayout >
    </ScrollView >
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Have you checked my above answer ?@Karuppu MGR

Comment: yeah bro but it hides all viewpagers

Comment: it will not hide viewpagers once you have data in it.